# Scraping info and presenting it in a key => value fashion in a nested hash?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following:

```
  department = data.css('#ref_2619534011')

  @department_hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}
  department.css('.narrowValue').each do | department |
    @department_hash["department"] << department.text
  end
```

which outputs something like this:

```
{"department"=>["15,721", "243,247", "510,260", "46,007", "14,106", "358", "5,787", "19,808"]}
```

Now I want to grab the title of those total numbers

```
 department.css('.refinementLink').each do
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
{"department"=>["Bird", "Cats", etc ]}
```

I want to mix both to produce a nested hash like this:

```
{departments: { "Pet Supplies": [ "Birds" : 15,721, "Cats" : 243,247, etc ] }}
```

How to accomplish that?

**EDIT:**

I tried this but didn't work:

```
 @department_hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}
  department.css('li').each do | department |
    department_title = department.css('.refinementLink').text
    department_count = department.css('.narrowValue').text[/[\d,]+/]
  end 

  @department_hash["department"] = Hash[department_title.zip(department_count)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) to combine both arrays:

```
numbers = ["15,721", "243,247"]
animals = ["Birds", "Cats"]

Hash[animals.zip(numbers)]
#=> {"Birds"=>"15,721", "Cats"=>"243,247"}
```

**Regarding your edit:**

Since you already have `department_title` and `department_count` in place, something like this inside your loop should work:

```
@department_hash = {}
department.css('li').each do |department|
  department_title = ...
  department_count = ...
  @department_hash["department"] ||= {}   # ensure empty hash
  @department_hash["department"][department_title] = department_count
end
```

Comment: I tried incorporating that to my code but it didn't work. Please see my **EDIT**

Comment: @alexchenco `department_title` and `department_count` are not available outside your loop. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way how can I add the "Pet Supplies" part (just as a title for that nested hash?)

Comment: I think `@department_hash["department"]["Pet Supplies"] = ...` is the syntax you are looking for.